# C++ Builder XE5 linker is unable to open WINDOWS.OBJ

Tags: c++, winapi, linker-errors, delphi-xe5, c++builder-xe5

While trying to compile a C++ project in XE5 I get the following error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'WINDOWS.OBJ'
```

I already use "Windows" instead of "WinTypes" and "WinProcs" in my Delphi units.

Under "Delphi compiler" -> "Unit scopes" there is also the "WinAPI" entry.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like your search paths do not include an entry for `$(BDS)\lib\$(Platform)\$(Config)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I tried to add "$(BDS)\lib\$(Platform)\$(Config)" to "C++ Compiler->Directories and Conditionals->Include file search patch" but the paths was not valid.

Then I added this:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\lib\win32\debug"

However I still get "[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'WINDOWS.OBJ'"

Comment: As you were told in the Embarcadero forums, the Options dialog does not resolve `$(Platform)` and `$(Config)` correctly but they are still valid to use, and you should use `release` instead of `$(Config)` and let the IDE/compiler update `release` to `debug` for you during debug compiling, as it has special handling for the `release` folder.